# copy package from schema B to schema C

Tags: oracle

I am in the next situation: I am using oracle 11g. I am connected to an user, lets say schema1, where are a lot of permissions. I want to create a script which will copy the Package1 (and its body) from schema2 to schema3.

The script will be executed from schema1.

PS: I already look for a solution and I am not interested in export/import or in using other tools from toad, sql developer etc.

Comment: Did you consider using [Data Pump API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm) in [Network-Mode Import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL806)?

Answer (score 1):

**One way** of doing this on a low level basis is by reading the `USER_SOURCE` for the corresponding package. In PL/SQL you could loop over the lines and add each line to an array (/table) of type `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A`, lets call this variable '`sqlTable`'.

The first line of your `sqlTable` contains the package name, with a little String manipulation you should be able to change the name from 'PACKAGE_NAME' to 'SCHEMA'.'PACKAGE_NAME'.

Then using `DBMS_SQL` package perform the following steps:

1. `cur = DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR; -- cur is of type pls_integer`
2. `DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlTable, sqlTable.first, sqlTable.last, false, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);`
3. `DBMS_SQL.execute(cur)`

**Another way** is to spool the output of the USER_SOURCE to a file, connect to the other schema and load / execute the file there. See [this](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?3071-Copying-a-package-from-one-schema-to-another).

Comment: is there also a possibility of using dbms_metadata.get_ddl?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can address your task combining `DBMS_DATAPUMP` and `DBMS_METADATA` PL/SQL packages.

Comment: the solution with USER_SOURCE is not working because the table USER_SOURCE contains the source of the current schema. You cannot use it to see the source from another user.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this as schema1, you could just write into your script to temporarily log in as schema2, use the USER_SOURCE solution, generate your script, log in as schema3, then run the script.